# Proguard ignoring -assumenosideeffects while exporting Export Signed Application Package

Tags: android, proguard

Ubuntu  12.04

intellij idea 12 Community Edition

SDK 16

Android 4.1.2

Created test project with one activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        android.util.Log.d("0000", "start MyActivity");
    }
}
```

**project.properties**

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-16
```

**proguard-project.txt**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int i(...);
}
```

Main goal: strip Logs from release version of the app, NOT working

Steps:
Build -> Generate signed APK...
After installation signed apk into device LogCat show all logs:

```
12-24 15:59:08.773: DEBUG/0000(2074): start MyActivity
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option "Build -> Generate signed APK..." in IntelliJ doesn't seem to run ProGuard, so it doesn't optimize or obfuscate the application. You can run "ant release" instead.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you give details? I assume we need to create a build.xml in order for the ant release to work?